# Facebook Graph API: page_fans_online, localizing dates to where the business is located

Tags: facebook-graph-api, timezone

I am trying to replicate the data that is used in "When your fans are online" section" of a business page's insights dashboard. I am using the following parameters in the /insights/page_fans_online api call which returns the data I am after:

```
parameters={'period':'day','since':'2018-10-20T07:00:00','until':'2018-10-21T07:00:00','access_token':page_token['access_token'][0]}
```

The data returned can be seen below, where:

```
end_time = end_time (based on the since & until dates in the parameters)
name = metric
apiHours = hour of day returned
localDate = localized date (applied manually)
localHours = - 6 hour offset to localize to Auckland/New Zealand (applied 
manually to replicate what is seen on the insights dashboard.
fansOnline =  number of unique page fans online during that hour
```

Data:

```
end_time                  name              apiHours localDate   localHours   fansOnline                             
2018-10-21T07:00:00+0000  page_fans_online  0        2018-10-19     18          21
                                            1        2018-10-19     19          29
                                            2        2018-10-19     20          20
                                            3        2018-10-19     21          18
                                            4        2018-10-19     22          20
                                            5        2018-10-19     23          15
                                            6        2018-10-19     0           4
                                            7        2018-10-19     1           6
                                            8        2018-10-19     2           5
                                            9        2018-10-19     3           8
                                            10       2018-10-19     4           17
                                            11       2018-10-19     5           19
                                            12       2018-10-19     6           26
                                            13       2018-10-19     7           24
                                            14       2018-10-19     8           20
                                            15       2018-10-19     9           22
                                            16       2018-10-19     10          19
                                            17       2018-10-19     11          22
                                            18       2018-10-19     12          18
                                            19       2018-10-19     13          18
                                            20       2018-10-19     14          18
                                            21       2018-10-19     15          18
                                            22       2018-10-19     16          21
                                            23       2018-10-19     17          28
```

It took a while to work out that the data returned when pulling page_fans_online using the parameters specified above is for Wednesday October 19th, for a New Zealand business page.

If we look at the last row in the data above:

```
end_time = 2018-10-21
apiHours = 23
localDate = 2018-10-19
localHours = 17
fansOnline = 28
```

It is saying on 2018-10-21 @ 11 pm there were 28 unique fans online. This translates to , on 2018-10-19 @ 5 pm there were 28 unique fans online when the dates and times are manually localized, (I worked the offset out by checking the "When your fans online" graphs on the page insights).

There is a -54 hour offset between 2018-10-21 11:00 pm and 2018-10-19 5:00 pm, and my question is, what is the logic used behind the end_time and hour of day returned by the page_fans_online insights metric and is there any info regarding how this should be localized depending on what country the business is located?

There is only a simple description of what page_fans_online is in the page/insights docs and says the hours are in PST/PDT but that does not help with localizing the date and hour of day:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/insights